# Hyperlink to figure (reference) in PDF links to incorrect figure

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, captions

I have a document with a few sections, I'm new to LaTeX so I'm just using the `article` class. I want the figure numbers to restart in each section. I did this with `\setcounter{figure}{0}` at the start of each section, and I figure this is somehow related to (causing) my problem but I just can't figure out a solution.

The problem is when I click on a hyper-link in a figure reference to, say, Figure 1 in Section 2, it will take you back to the first figure one (back in Section 1 in this case), even if the reference specifies the correct figure by name/label.

I'm using XeLaTeX and the `multicols` environment so I've included that in my MWE but I don't think they are related to the problem. I'm also using a custom `\Figure` so that the figure fits in the column nicely.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper, hmargin=1.5in, vmargin=1in, marginparsep=7pt, marginparwidth=.6in}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[small,bf,hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}  
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{section1}]
(Figure~\ref{fig:fig1}
\begin{Figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apple.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{caption}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{Figure}
\end{multicols}

\newpage
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{section2}]
(Figure~\ref{fig:fig2}
\begin{Figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apple.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{caption}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{Figure}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Here is a compiled PDF for your convenience: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3730003/mwe6.pdf

To easily witness the problem, go to the 2nd page and click on the hyperlink in the reference to the figure, it will take you back to the first page.

I've been trying to use:

```
\renewcommand*{\theHfigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

after the start of each section and this works if I use `section{}` instead of `section*{}` but with 'section*' the 'section' number stays at 0 with `\arabic{section}` and `\thesection`.

Note: I'm not completely sure what `hypcap=false` does but I was getting errors from the `caption` package with the default `hypcap=true` so I switched it to `false` but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you want to use unnumbered sections?

Comment: This is for a short document, specifically a job application package, with a cover-letter, cv, and research proposal, just don't want/need to number each of the sections.

Comment: Silly question; have you tried using `\phantomsection` before your `\section*{...}` commands? I think this may increment the necessary counters without extra effort.

Comment: Ah, no. Sorry, I'm seeing the problem now.

Comment: For the non-working hyperlink see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45935/hypcap-not-working-with-custom-figure-environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Two table counters and hyperref links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26469/two-table-counters-and-hyperref-links) and [hide section numbering but continue adding-up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30039/hide-section-numbering-but-continue-adding-up) for the ideas and the help of @cmhughes's answer. I am now using this combination which seems to work well.

I put in a new `section` command `unnumsec` which replicates `section*` while incrementing the `section` counter:

```
\newcommand{\unnumsec}[1]{\refstepcounter{section}\section*{#1}}
```

Now the code from @cmhughes will work properly to reset the figure counter:

```
\makeatletter
     \@addtoreset{figure}{section}
\makeatother
```

And to ensure that hyperlinks point correctly to figures with the same number in different sections I put this just after `\begin{document}`

```
\renewcommand*{\theHfigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your current approach is that the hyperlink is being duplicated- as you'll see in your log file,

```
destination with the same identifier (name{figure.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

You can get round this by deleting the `\setcounter{figure}{0}` and adding

```
\makeatletter
     \@addtoreset{figure}{section}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble- this resets the figure number every section, and keeps hyperlinks working the way you want. This method works for uses of `\section` but does not work for `\section*`... perhaps someone knows how to implement the reset for `\section*`?

A complete MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[small,bf,hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}

\makeatletter
    \@addtoreset{figure}{section}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{section1}]
(Figure~\ref{fig:fig1}
\begin{Figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apple.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{caption}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{Figure}
\end{multicols}

\newpage
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{section2}]
(Figure~\ref{fig:fig2}
\begin{Figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apple.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{another caption}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{Figure}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: :( It's not working for me, the figure number doesn't reset in each new section.

Comment: @s0rce try it now- replaced with `\section*` with `\section`- do you need it to reset with `\section*` as well?

Comment: Yes, I do need that. I don't want numbered sections, well at least I don't want the number to show up in the document. ` \@addtoreset{figure}{section*}` doesn't appear to work.

Comment: I could manually \addtocounter{section}{1} after each \section* but it would be nice if one command at the beginning could do everything! This should do the trick: \newcommand{\unnumsec}[1]{\refstepcounter{section}\section*{#1}}

Comment: @s0rce are you sure you want your numbers to reset in `section*` as well? this is going to make referencing them quite hard, both from the author and the reader perspective...