# Hypcap not working with custom figure environment

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, captions, multicol

I'm trying to use `caption` with `hypcap=true` so that cross-reference hyperlinks will go to the figure instead of the figure caption. However, I'm using a `multicol` environment with a custom figure environment so that the floats place well in the two-column document.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[small,bf,hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}
\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[all]{hypcap} %I don't know if this line is needed

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{section1}]
Figure~\ref{fig:fig1}
\begin{Figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apple.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{caption}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{Figure}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I'm using XeLaTeX but I don't think that changes anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `float` package to use `H` placement specifier:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[small,bf,hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{section1}]
Figure~\ref{fig:fig1}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{apple.jpg}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm just figuring this stuff out but what exactly is the difference between [h] and [H]? Thanks!

Comment: @s0rce: You should read Frank Mittelbach's answer the following post: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/5764)

Answer (score 5):

There are two reasons why your hyperlink is not working correctly:

1. When using the `hypcap` package the `caption` package will not place hyperlink anchors anymore, since the `hypcap` package is taking responsibility for this task. So don't use it here, otherwise no hyperlink anchor will be placed at all, at least not by the `caption` package. See section 6.6 "hypcap" in the `caption` package manual. (As an alternative one could use `\capstart` here, see `hypcap` package manual for details.)
2. When using `\captionof` the `caption` package does only know where the caption is placed, but does not know where the figure actually starts, i.e. where it should place the hyperlink anchor. So use `\captionsetup{type=figure}` for this task and avoid using `\captionof`. See section 6.5 "hyperref" in the `caption` package manual, especially the paragraph "\captionof{...}{...} vs. \captionsetup{type=...}+\caption{...}"

Your example document, modified:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[small,bf,hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}%
   \captionsetup{type=figure}}% \captionsetup{type=figure} added
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}
\usepackage[unicode, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks]{hyperref} 
%\usepackage[all]{hypcap} % No, this line is not needed

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{section1}]
Figure~\ref{fig:fig1}
\begin{Figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{apple.jpg}
\caption{caption} % \captionof replaced by \caption
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{Figure}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```