# Automatic placement of picture in multicol environment at top, bottom, or middle of column

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, multicol

Having a `multicol` document spanning over several pages with pictures (`includegraphics`, `width=\columnwidth`), I am looking for a way that LaTeX chooses the best position for the picture or at least places the picture at the bottom or top or middle of a column. The place of the `\includegraphics` command is derived from the converted HTML page and therefore arbitrary.

The problem now is that

```
xxxx pict xxxx
     xxxx xxxx
xxxx xxxx xxxx
     xxxx xxxx
xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

Because the picture cannot be placed at the bottom, it is placed at the top of a new column and the column before is stretched to fit the space.

Ideal would be:

```
xxxx xxxx xxxx
xxxx xxxx xxxx
xxxx pict xxxx
xxxx xxxx xxxx
xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3} rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber
rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber
rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber

rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber
rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber
rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber

rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber
rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber
rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber

rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber
rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber
rhabarber rhabarber rhabarberarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber
rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber rhabarber
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=100pt]{dummy.jpg}
asdf

\lipsum

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46014/how-to-float-figure-within-multicol-text is the same like that. However, is there a way to have the lines at certain positions be written to a external file so that a script could adjust the position of the picture (i.e. what words are in the line at 450pt from bottom,1st column?)

Comment: I agree, it's a duplicate. If there is some way to solve this problem, it should be discussed over at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46014/how-to-float-figure-within-multicol-text.