# Link to top of figure while using adjustbox environment

Tags: links

Is it possible to label a nofloat figure/graphic within an `adjustbox` environment such that the link (using `hyperref`) goes to the top of the figure instead to the caption below?

The figure must be placed within the `itemize` with correct centering (current linewidth, not whole textwidth of the document) for both the figure and the caption and additionally a nofloat such that the link goes to the top of the figure.

I get the warning:
**The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for this(caption) particular \caption**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \Blindtext[1][2]\Blindtext[1]
        \begin{adjustbox}{
                center=\linewidth,
                caption=Some caption,
                label=a,
                nofloat=figure,
            }
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \clip(-5.686675053232457,-3.16893917565149) rectangle (5.579414724686105,0.6921754200738994);
            \draw [line width=1.2pt,domain=-5.686675053232457:9.579414724686105]plot(\x,{(--4.514220105043796-1.8219356725415592*\x)/1.894960446786564});
            \draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt,domain=-5.686675053232457:9.579414724686105] plot(\x,{(--1.6188066144426525-1.0979714604086213*\x)/-0.3751399196759637});
            \draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt,domain=-5.686675053232457:9.579414724686105] plot(\x,{(--11.463481791986391--1.2426776436313691*\x)/-5.670646727250561});
            \draw [line width=1.2pt,domain=-5.686675053232457:9.579414724686105] plot(\x,{(--0.4039090361160175--0.6586822831185679*\x)/-0.27723191082856635});
            \draw [line width=1.2pt,domain=-5.686675053232457:9.579414724686105] plot(\x,{(-2.9955647165449215--0.8716146065783191*\x)/4.89799733746727});    
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{adjustbox}
        \item \Blindtext[1] 
    \end{itemize}
see \ref{a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code used by `adjustbox` does not support this feature of other packages yet. I will add this support in the next version of the package. Thank you very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45944/136549) one can define a new environment, which then behaves like a (nofloat) figure environment:

```
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}%
   \captionsetup{type=figure}}% \captionsetup{type=figure} added
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}
```

This works now. It's not necessary to use `adjustbox`.

Comment: You could just redefine the `adjnofloat` environment used by `adjustbox` to create the `nofloat`. This possibility is explained in the package manual. Based on your code: `\renewenvironment{adjnofloat}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}\captionsetup{type=#1}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}`